# warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale on GCE instances

Tags: linux

We are not sure when this issue exactly started, but we recently found that when we log in GCE instance (`debian-8-jessie-v20170110`, in `us-west1-b` region), following warning message always appeared on console;

> warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (ja_JP.UTF-8)

Do you guys have any idea why we suddenly started to get this warning message with GCE instances? We didn't change any locale related settings by ourselves.

After running `sudo localedef -f UTF-8 -i ja_JP ja_JP.UTF-8`, the warning message has disappeared, but it would be helpful if we could know why the issue was happening.

Answer (score 4):

Your remote host doesn't support same locale configured on your local (see `locale`).

To ignore the warning, you can set `LC_ALL` to `C` before connecting, e.g.

```
LC_ALL=C ssh user@example.com
```

To install some specific language pack on the host, run:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-jp
```

To check all supported locale, run: `locale -a`.